# Listbox sorting using bubble method skipping first item in listbox

Tags: excel, vba, bubble-sort

I need help customizing this bubble sort code so that it will skip the first item in the listbox and only sort a-z on the rest of the items in the listbox. I'm lost and need some directions. Thanks

```
    Dim j As Long
    Dim sTemp As String
    Dim sTemp2 As String
    Dim LbList As Variant

    'Store the list in an array for sorting
    LbList = Me.WorksheetListBox.List

    'Bubble sort the array on the first value
    For i = LBound(LbList, 1) To UBound(LbList, 1) - 1
        For j = i + 1 To UBound(LbList, 1)
            If LbList(i, 0) > LbList(j, 0) Then
                'Swap the first value
                sTemp = LbList(i, 0)
                LbList(i, 0) = LbList(j, 0)
                LbList(j, 0) = sTemp

                'Swap the second value
                sTemp2 = LbList(i, 1)
                LbList(i, 1) = LbList(j, 1)
                LbList(j, 1) = sTemp2
            End If
        Next j
    Next i

'Remove the contents of the listbox
        Me.WorksheetListBox.Clear

        'Repopulate with the sorted list
        Me.WorksheetListBox.List = LbList
```

Comment: `For i = LBound(LbList, 1)+1...`

Comment: holy fock, you are an genius...